# Ember.js - stuck with auto index in populating models in table (handlebar template)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to populate the route's model using auto numbering 1,2,3 in my handlebar template and not using autogenerated db id as in the picture, as those are mess up when record is deleted, the problem is @index is no longer supported in handlebar.

---

[image]

---

my Route:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
     return this.store.find('post');
  }
);
```

my controller:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   actions: {
      delete: function(post) {
        post.deleteRecord();
        post.get('isDeleted'); // => true
        post.save(); // => DELETE to /posts/1
      },

      adNewPost: function() {
         this.transitionToRoute('new');
      }
   }
});
```

My model and RESTAdapter

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
   postId: DS.attr('string'),
   title: DS.attr('string'),
   author: DS.attr('string'),
   body: DS.attr('string')
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'emberpostsrest/api'
});
```

My template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
<h1>Posts List</h1>

<button {{action 'addNewPost' }}>Add New Posts</button>
<p></p>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Index</th>
    <th scope="col">Title</th>
    <th scope="col">Author</th>
    <th scope="col">Body</th>
    <th scope="col">Delete</th>
  </tr>

  {{#each model}}
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{#link-to 'post' this}}
          {{id}} //<---- HOW TO ADD AN AUTO INDEX HELPER HERE (1,2,3, ETC
                 //      AND NOT USING MODEL'S ID
        {{/link-to}}
      </td>
      <td>{{title}}</td>
      <td>{{author}}</td>
      <td>{{body}}</td>
      <td><a href="" {{action 'delete' this}}>X</a></td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>

<div>
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

---

**UPDATED WITH ANSWER AS SUGGESTED :D**

The CSS

```
table {
   counter-reset: id;
}

.id-column:before {
   counter-increment: id; 
   content: counter(id);
}
```

The template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
<h1>Posts List</h1>

<button {{action 'addNewPost' }}>Add New Posts</button>
<p></p>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Index</th>
    <th scope="col">Title</th>
    <th scope="col">Author</th>
    <th scope="col">Body</th>
    <th scope="col">Delete</th>
  </tr>

  {{#each}}
    <tr>
      <td class="id-column">
      </td>
      <td>
        {{#link-to 'post' this}}
          {{title}}
        {{/link-to}}
      </td>
      <td>{{author}}</td>
      <td>{{body}}</td>
      <td><a href="" {{action 'delete' this}}>X</a></td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>

<div>
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

The updated browser output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS counters instead of mucking around with Ember things. It appears that there are some problems with the old `_view.contentIndex` approach that may be due to recent changes in Ember. Basic approach would be something like:

```
<table>
  {{! headers }}
  {{#each model}}
  <tr>
    <td class="id-column">
      {{#link-to 'post' this}}
        {{id}} //<---- HOW TO ADD AN AUTO INDEX HELPER HERE (1,2,3, ETC
               //      AND NOT USING MODEL'S ID
      {{/link-to}}
    </td>
```

```css
table {
  counter-reset: id;
}
.id-column:before {
  counter-increment: id; 
  content: counter(id);
}
```

Comment: man, this is making me more confused :D. Why Ember as an awesome framework neglect those very simple @index in handlebar. I thought Ember got everything.

Comment: you're awesome, salute :D. The best answer and the simplest of all the questions on auto index in table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_view.contentIndex` to get the current index in the loop. It is however zero-based so it would count 0, 1, 2. That could easily be fixed using a handlebar helper that simply adds 1 to the value though.

Comment: Trid as per your suggestion - {{#link-to 'post' this}}               {{_view.contentIndex}} {{/link-to}} doesn't print anything. There is no output.

Comment: I'm just starting learning Ember - starting last week. I'm still not up to View or ArrayController or anything related.